# Uninstalling SharePoint Designer 2010 fails with error "OSETUP.DLL cannot be loaded"

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, error

I'm trying to uninstall SharePoint Designer 2010 (32 bit) from my client PC. When I go to Control Panel > Uninstall a program > SharePoint Designer 2010 > Uninstall, I receive the following error:

> A required
>   C:\users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Temp\Setup00000f90\OSETUP.DLL cannot
>   be loaded. This may indicate that the file is missing or damaged.

This error prevents me from re-installing SharePoint Designer 2010 in another language.

How can i fix this error so I can re-install from language A to language B?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download and install SharePoint designer as if it was never on your computer. This should replace any missing files from the original install. Then uninstall it.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=16573

Comment: Downloaded the SharePoint Designer 2010 installation file. Next I executed this file and chose the Remove option. SharePoint Designer 2010 successfully uninstalled this way without the OSETUP.DLL error. Thank you Taber-Brown!